# how to run java script file after invoke with ajax and append to the output

Tags: php, javascript, json, jquery

My problem with the javascript file run through the AJAX call is

for example :

index.php

```
$(function(){
$(".btn-ajax").click(function(){
$.getJSON('ajax.php',function(data){

jsInc(data['js'][0]['src']);

$("#response").html(data['html']);

});
});

function jsInc($src){
 var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            var script=document.createElement("script");
            script.type='text/javascript';
            script.src = $src;
            head.appendChild(script);
}
```

ajax.php

```
$arr['js'][] = array('src'=>'js.js');
$arr['html'] = '<input type="button" class="btn" value="show message"/>';

echo json_encode($arr);
```

js.js

```
$(function(){

$(".btn").on('click',function(){
    alert("test !");
    });

});
```

but when execute ajax request and append input button to the index.php file this button click event not worked!

please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to get script via AJAX right? You can use [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/):

```
$.getScript("script.js");
```

> Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happeneing is your first loading the JS which binds the click listener and then loading the Button. SO the listener doesnt get bound

Try reversing the order like:

```
$("#response").html(data['html']);
jsInc(data['js'][0]['src']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rebinding the click function after the Ajax call (success):

```
$.ajax({... 
       success: function(data) {
           $(".btn").click(clickFunction);
           } 
});


$(".btn").on('click', clickFunction);

function clickFunction() {
    alert("test !");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your function in js.js to be a delegate function.

```
$(function(){

$('body').on('click','.btn',function(){
    alert("test !");
    });

});
```

When you do it this way.  The .btn element doesn't even need to be present before the script is run.  It attaches the event to the body tag prior to checking if the .btn element exists.

Comment: thanks @Bluetoft Im using .live() and now worked correctness! :)